# swagger ui with collection (List) input parameter for Jax Rs resource

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

How to configure swaggerui to display correct parameter datatype for JAX-RS resources which have collection input parameters?

Below is a sample groovy JAX-RS resource. Its input is of type `List<User>`

```
@POST
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Create(s) users", response = User, responseContainer = "List")
Response createUsers(List<User> questions) {
}
```

In the swagger UI, I see the List with empty type populated instead of `User`.  It works fine for output parameters. Using `ApiOperation` annotation, I could specify for response type.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create(s) users", response = User, responseContainer = "List")
```

For input parameters, How do I see List of User model schema in the swagger UI?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using @ApiParam on List:

```
@POST
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Create(s) users", response = User, responseContainer = "List")
Response createUsers(@ApiParam("description") List<User> questions) {
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thnx